# Eclipse mars, cannot open in mac os x

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-mars

Eclipse mars, I installed it on my Mac OS X 10.11.3 it launched after finishing the installation but when I quit the app and trying to open again it cannot be opened with a dialog box message "Eclipse quit unexpectedly" 
[image]

Comment: In its current form, it is very hard to have an idea what might have gone wrong. I recommend checking the logs inside the application, maybe trying to start it from the command line, and checking your installed Java versions (e.g. Eclipse Mars requires Java 7 to start).

Answer (score 2):

There is an alias file in the folder that is extracted. It's called eclipse with no extension. Don't click the eclipse.app icon. This worked for me because it brings up the terminal window. It says it's a unix file, just click ok and Eclipse runs perfectly. Copy that alias to the desktop not the app. I don't know why this work, but it does. FYI IntelliJ didn't have this issues.

This is for eclipse luna on a MacBook air i5 with Sierra.